# What is going on in this solution to the Fizzbuzz question?

Tags: fizzbuzz

```
      for (let number = 0; number <= 100; number++ ) {
            let output = ""
            if (number % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz"
            if (number % 5 == 0) output += "buzz"
            console.log(output || number)
  
            }
```

I understand why it finds the modulo for 3 and 5.  But why does this also find the modulo for 15?  (The question asks to also find the numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5 and print "Fizzbuzz").

I was able to solve the question in a different manner and was offered this as one of the ideal solutions.

Is the += after the output somehow multiplying the other two remainders?

Comment: In general, if you want to learn how/why a piece of code works, then load it in a debugger and step through it line by line. Chrome has a built-in Javascript debugger that's pretty good!

Comment: Thank you jorn!  I think I understand each individual piece but I am drawing a blank on how this reaches 3 and 5 modulos combined.  I know it is something simple or right in front of my eyes but I just can't get it.

Comment: Note that there's no `else` before the second `if`

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about the use of `+=`, then it is a short form of writing `output=output+"Fizz"`. Hence instead of writing the above one we can simply write `output+="Fizz"`

Comment: Why does this also output the modulo for 3 and 5 together?  It seems to me I should have to write a third if loop ( number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 == 0) output += "Fizzbuzz

Comment: @DanteArceneaux: no, you don't need to, because these ifs are independent / not mutually exclusive. That is, number 15 will trigger both checks for 3 and 5.

Comment: This program actually checks if it is divisible by 3 first, If yes then add Fizz then checks divisibility for 5, if yes then add buzz

Comment: Thank you so much guys!  Would have taken me forever to figure out on my own.  I understand now

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my question is that the program runs both checks independently. When it reaches 15 (or any other number divisible by both 3 and 5), it will simply add "Fizz" and "buzz" together to create "Fizzbuzz".